# Assign_block_vars in multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, block, multidimensional-array

I have a unique problem that I cannot seem to find or figure out the answer to because I am trying to do a few things at once. I've tried researching each thing to find out the answer but it is unfortunately escaping me. :C

Essentially, I want to print an array inside of an array using assign_block_vars. Here is the HTML code that I would be using to display the SQL/PHP information -

```
* Active Players * (where active = 1 )
<!-- BEGIN activeplayers -->

<a href="{activeplayers.organizer}">{activeplayers.username}</a><br>

    <!-- BEGIN charlist -->
    - {charlist.charname}, {charlist.charrace}<br>
    <!-- END charlist -->
    <br><br>
* Inactive Players * (where active = 0 )
<!-- END activeplayers -->

<!-- BEGIN inactiveplayers -->

<a href="{inactiveplayers.organizer}">{inactiveplayers.username}</a><br>

    <!-- BEGIN charlist -->
    - {charlist.charname}, {charlist.charrace}<br>
    <!-- END charlist -->
    <br><br>

<!-- END inactiveplayers -->
```

The information is coming from two tables, like so:

```
table: roster_players
-------------------------------------------------
| username   | organizer             | active   |
-------------------------------------------------
| Amy        | http://www.google.com | 1        |
| John       | http://www.msn.com    | 0        |
| David      | http://www.google.com | 1        |
| Jane       | http://www.msn.com    | 1        |
-------------------------------------------------

table: roster_characters
-------------------------------------------------
| player     | charname              | charrace |
-------------------------------------------------
| Amy        | Apple                 | Elf      |
| Amy        | Turkey                | Human    |
| David      | Cupholder             | Elf      |
| John       | Blueberry             | Human    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**Where my problem is!** This is the PHP/SQL I have tried working with and I am sure something is wrong with my foreach() statements, but I can't figure it out. I intended on running the code below twice, once for where p.active = 1 and again for p.active = 0, to make two separate lists.

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.active AS active, p.username AS username, p.organizer AS organizer, p.active AS active, c.player AS player, c.charname AS charname, c.charrace AS charrace  
FROM `roster_characters` c
INNER JOIN `roster_players` as p
ON c.player = p.username 
where p.active = 1';

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);

$playerlist = array();
$characterlist = array();

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{ 

foreach ($playerlist as $player => $playerlist)

   {  $template->assign_block_vars('activeplayers', array (
    'USERNAME' => $player,
        'ORGANIZER' => $row['organizer'],

    ));

    foreach ($playerlist as $row['username'] => $row['charname'])

    {       
        $template->assign_block_vars('players.charlist', array(
             'CHARNAME'    => $row['charname'],
             'CHARRACE'    => $row['charrace'],

        )); 

       }

    }
}
```

The end result would look like this:

```
* Active Players * (where active = 1 )
Amy 
- Apple, Elf
- Turkey, Human

David 
- Cupholder, Elf

* Inactive Players * (where active = 0 )
John
- Blueberry, Human
```

Thank you for your time and help!!!